# How to convert a matrix into a sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

If I have a matrix:

```
row 1)1 0 0 4
row 2)0 0 0 0
row 3)5 1 0 0
row 4)0 5 0 0
row 5)0 0 0 9
```

How would I put it in a sparse matrix format:

```
a(0)(0) = ? a(0)(1) = ? a(0)(2) = ?
a(1)(0) = ? a(1)(1) = ? a(1)(2) = ?
a(2)(0) = ? a(2)(1) = ? a(2)(2) = ?
a(3)(0) = ? a(3)(1) = ? a(3)(2) = ?
a(4)(0) = ? a(4)(1) = ? a(4)(2) = ?
a(5)(0) = ? a(5)(1) = ? a(5)(2) = ?
```

I've tried looking on the internet but I couldn't find any help telling me how to do it.

Comment: (I believe this is a dupe, but I can't find the other thread.) Apply `SparseArray[]` to your original matrix to get the sparse form, e.g. `SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[4]]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
a = {{1, 0, 0, 4},
  {0, 0, 0, 0},
  {5, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 5, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 9}};
```

Then

```
sa = SparseArray[a]
```

Since `SparseArray` takes the default to be `0`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the link (How to | Work with Sparse Matrices) : "https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithSparseMatrices.html". Hope this help.

```
mat = SparseArray[{{1, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0,0}, {0, 0, 0, 9}}]

mat // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = SparseArray[{{1,1} -> 1, {3,1} -> 5, ....}]
```